# Give snippets names and true/false variable

Tags: jquery, variables

I have an entire document with **snippets** that I want to give names to and `=true;` variable and then call the name in a `<script>` tag in the **HTML** and to be able to set it to **false** or **true**.

How can I do that?

The snippet is :

```
$(".me").click(function() {
    $(".hidden").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Example of how I would do it:

```
enable_click_function: true;

if (self.settings.enable_click_function) {
    self.enableClickFunction();
}

enableClickFunction: function() {
    var self = this;
    $(".me").click(function() {
        $(".hidden").fadeIn(500);
    });
};
```

And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/ut3y328y/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the setter-getter pattern.

For example, create definition for your configuration. A "settings" object to hold initializer properties. Methods for your snippets, which can be used later for switching event bindings on and off. Something like this:

***A small working demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ba3zz4b9/5/***

***Snippet:***

```js
/* Your config definition */
function config() {
    this.settings = {
        "enableEnter": false
    };
    this.executeEnableEnter = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            $(this).next().focus();
        };
    };
}

/*
  Now you can define getter/setter for each of those settings properties. 
  Setter will use jQuery `.on` and `.off` to bind/unbind the relevant method, 
  depending on your use-case. Something like this:
*/

Object.defineProperty(config.prototype, 'enableEnter', {
    get: function() { return  this.settings.enableEnter; }, 
    set: function(value) {
        this.settings.enableEnter = value;
        if (value) {
            $("input").on("keypress", this.executeEnableEnter);
        } else {
            $("input").off("keypress", this.executeEnableEnter);
        }
    }
});

/*
  Now you can create your config object and use it. 
  For example, if you want to enable enter key behaviour on a checkbox state, 
  then you could:
*/

var configObject = new config;

$("#chk").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) { configObject.enableEnter = true; } 
    else { configObject.enableEnter = false; }
  
    $("#result").text("Enter key enabled = " + this.checked + ", Press enter on first input to focus the next.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" /><input type="text" /><hr />
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" /><label for="chk">Enable/Disable Enter</label>
<br /><p id="result"></p>
```

.

Comment: Woohoo, this works like a charm, one more thing though, how do I call only the setting in my HTML script tag?

Comment: I didn't understand. You only have to call like this: `configObject.enableEnter = true;` nothing else.

Comment: Well I marked this as the answer and a +1 cause it works nicely but I tried '$(document).ready(function(){ configObject.enableEnter = true; });' in my HTML and it's not taking course :)

Comment: Oups, sorry, my bad, figured it out :)) Thanks for the code and everything :D Have a great day !!

Comment: I am struggling with something, let's say I want to enable enter key behavior only by writing it in the head, and not by check state...I wasn't able to do it...sorry for bothering..

Comment: In that case just call `configObject.enableEnter = true;` anywhere after the definition and object instantiation.

Comment: ^^ Thanks, I was calling it directly in my head tag and it was not working, I have the snippets in a different .js file. And I wanted to have the script in that document but manipulate the variable from my head. :)

Comment: Of course. Just keep the definition part in another js. And make sure that js is included before you instantiate and use the configObject.

Comment: Well, my js in included and the definition is in another js but oddly I still can't define the variable from the script tag in my head...odd..

Comment: Well.. its very difficult to troubleshoot from here... all I can say is just make it doubly sure that your javascripts are loaded in correct order. `jQuery > Your Class Library > Your page specific code`.

Comment: They are, anyway, it's ok, I'll figure it out ^^ Thanks for everything :)

Comment: Hei, I found a "simpler" way of doing this, check out my answer in the page and please give me a feedback if this is practical :)

Comment: Yup. This is good indeed. In this way, you have to add your code first and then add the external js (the other way around). And yes, it will be static.. meaning during runtime, if dynamically you want to disable depending on some condition, then you won't be able to do that.

Comment: I know it will be static, your version is more flexible but what I needed was exactly this. I wanted to be able to enable/disable the functions only from my CMS interface, not in the UI. Thanks again.

Comment: That's great then. It serves your purpose and that's important. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a "simpler" way of doing this...

***Just add this in the  tag:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var enable_fade_in = true;
</script>
```

***And this in a external js file***

```
$(function(){
settings={
    enableFadeIn:function() {
        var self = this;
        $(".me").click(function() {
            $(".hidden").fadeIn(500);
        });
    }
}

if ( enable_fade_in ) {
    settings.enableFadeIn();
}

});
```